# AWS S3 IAM policy to limit to single sub folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions, amazon-iam

**Scenario:** I have a simple S3 bucket that multiple users will be uploading files to. Each user should be uploading to a specific folder and only that folder - **no sub folders beyond that**. Inside that folder, they can upload anything they want. I have an IAM policy that currently limits to that users folder, but allows them to specify sub folders, which I do not want.

**Current IAM Policy JSON** which limits to a top level folder:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:GetObjectTagging"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::[MY_BUCKET]/[MY_FOLDER]/*"
    }]
}
```

**Proposed IAM Policy JSON** which I expected to further limit PutObject only on the folder specified, but this doesn't seem to allow uploading of any object?:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:GetObjectTagging"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::[MY_BUCKET]/[MY_FOLDER]/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "s3:prefix": [
                    "",
                    "[MY_FOLDER]/"
                ],
                "s3:delimiter": [
                    "/"
                ]
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

**Expected Results**

- **ALLOW** arn:aws:s3:::[MY_BUCKET]/[MY_FOLDER]/[MY_FILE].csv
- **ALLOW** arn:aws:s3:::[MY_BUCKET]/[MY_FOLDER]/[MY_FILE].parquet
- **ALLOW** arn:aws:s3:::[MY_BUCKET]/[MY_FOLDER]/[MY_FILE].txt
- **DENY** arn:aws:s3:::[MY_BUCKET]/[MY_FOLDER]/[MY_FOLDER1]/[MY FOLDER2]/[MY_FILE].txt
- **DENY** arn:aws:s3:::[MY_BUCKET]/[MY_FOLDER]/[MY_FOLDER1]/[MY_FILE].txt
- **DENY** arn:aws:s3:::[MY_BUCKET]/[MY_FOLDER]/[...N Folders]/[MY_FILE].txt

Comment: If you allow upload to a specific prefix e.g. `users/gbeaven/*` then you can't prevent uploads to 'folders' beneath that e.g. `users/gbeaven/dogs/snoopy.png`, at least not using IAM or bucket policies.

Comment: @jarmod How would you accomplish what I'm trying to do then? I don't feel like it should be this complicated. I have code that depends on the first "folder" of the key. If a user accidentally uploads with more than one key, it will throw off the code. With that being said, it seems prudent to handle the validation with an IAM policy instead of code.

Comment: You can't do this in an IAM or S3 bucket policy afaik so if you give IAM user fred permission to upload to `users/fred/*` then fred can create anything below that. All you can do is react to it, for example by triggering a Lambda function that moves files or deletes them or something else. Another option you have, rather than giving these users unfettered access to an S3 prefix is to vend them pre-signed URLs. Then *you* dictate the keys to which they can upload (but this may not be practical unless your users are interacting with S3 via an application that you control).

Comment: Perhaps it's worth understanding why you don't want to allow your users to create their own 'sub-folders' and manage their own hierarchy of files under their allocated prefix? Why is that an issue for your use case?

Comment: Because a user has no need for sub folders in our use case. A user is expected to load files to a data onboarding bucket to "their" folder, at which point a Lambda script fires and categorizes/places the data in our datalake. If the user always places in the correct location, I don't need to handle any user error in code. If the user does accidentally load multiple folders deep, without having the ability to limit to 1 subfolder and throwing an  "access denied" error to the user, the file will load silently, but will be handled by code. Just seems intuitive this could be handled by IAM policy.

Comment: Your Lambda will be invoked regardless of the actual S3 object key's sub-folder hierarchy. You then move the object into your Data Lake, at whatever key you want to move it to so *you* dictate the eventual sub-folder or lack thereof. Not quite understanding how the access denied is going to happen. In both the upload and the later download scenario, the user presumably has permissions on `s3://bucket/users/username/*` or similar (or even object by object in the Data Lake).

Comment: I'm aware that the event will fire Lambda, the purpose is to stop the event from happening, AKA, not allowing the upload in the first place. This is **already happening** on the prefix. In the IAM policy I posted in my original question, that user can PutObject to [MY_BUCKET]/[MY_FOLDER]/*, but they CANNOT Put to [MY_BUCKET]/[MY_FOLDER123]/[MY_FOLDER]/*. This is already denied by the IAM policy. I'm trying to essentially do the same thing, but on the end of the key..

Comment: As previously indicated, you can't do this within a policy. You have to react to the potential sub-folder upload in some sensible way, possibly accommodating it.

Answer (score 0):

There are no 'folders' in Amazon S3 as there are in a file system. What you see as folders, actually are just prefixes to the filename. The way, Amazon S3 works, you can restrict access to specific prefixes, but can't restrict the creation of additional prefixes underneath.

However, you can implement your requirement by utilizing Amazon S3 Events and a Lambda function. The process could look like this:

**1.** User stores file in Amazon S3

**2.** Amazon [S3 fires an event notification](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html), containing metadata, including object key (which represents the *filename*) including prefixes (which represent the *folders*).

**3.** Lambda function [triggered by the S3 Event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html) and processes the metadata by:

- checking the filename for subsequent slashes (`/`) after the allowed prefix (which indicates a 'subfolder')
- deleting the created file if it contains subsequent slashes

Comment: Right, which is what I am currently doing, but this "silently" handles the files that are uploaded, even if they are loaded incorrectly through the CLI. Yea, I could setup SNS alerts, but that seems like band-aids on band-aids.. It doesn't make sense to me that policies would only handle prefixes..

Comment: If you're missing specific features, please use the Feedback functionality in the AWS Management Console (on every page in the lower right) to send feature requests to the service teams. 90% of AWS' features are based on actual customer requests. Who knows, maybe there is a way to implement what you need.